# From character to binary (adding the left 0)

Tags: javascript

You can convert from char to binary in JS using this code:

```
var txt = "H";
bits = txt.charCodeAt(0).toString(2); //bits=1001000
```

The result is mathematically correct but no literally, i mean, there is a missing 0 to the left, that again, is correct, but I wonder if there is a way to make it consider the left zeros.

Comment: Having 8 bits is convention, not necessity. You can add the zeros manually. A simple `while (bits.length < 8) bits = '0' + bits;` would ensure it's 8 bits by the time the loop is over.

Comment: Could you not just check the string length and prepend with 0 to fill up the requisite number of characters?

Comment: @Chris of course, but I wonder if there is no "direct" method to have the conversion with the 0

Comment: @DomingoSL - There is no "direct" support for formatting numbers as strings with field widths and padding, the way you can with `printf` in C (etc) or `format` in Lisp (etc).  You can use various tricks to build a string of `0`s to prepend to the string, but you still have to do it more or less "manually".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a byte? Try this:

```
var txt = "H",
    bits = txt.charCodeAt(0).toString(2),
    aByte = new Array(9 - bits.length).join('0') + bits;
```

The snippet creates a new array with length of missing bits + 1, then it converts the newly created array to a string with amount of zeroes needed. `9` is the wanted "byte length" + 1.

However, this is relatively slow method, if you're having a time-critical task, I'd suggest you to use `while` or `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

`charCodeAt()` returns the code of a character, which is a general number.
A number itself does not have any kind of preffered alignment.
By convention numbers are printed without any leading zeros.

In fact, `charCodeAt()` returns unicode character code,
which in general can take more than 8 bits to store.
Therefore such behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

var bits = txt.charCodeAt( 0 ).toString( 2 );

var padding = 8 - bits.length;

res = [ ];

res.push( new Array( padding+1 ).join( '0' ) + bits );